# error after typing "node enrollAdmin.js" on windows

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

> node enrollAdmin.js

```
error: [FabricCAClientService.js]:  Failed to enroll admin, error:%o message=Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: con
nect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054], stack=Error: Calling enrollment endpoint fail
ed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]
    at ClientRequest.request.on (C:\Users\Nibir Hira\go\src\github.com\hyperledg
er\fabric-samples\fabcar\javascript\node_modules\fabric-ca-client\lib\FabricCACl
ient.js:487:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
Failed to enroll admin user "admin": Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed w
ith error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]
```

Where should I do corrections? The  file `registeradmin.js` is not even working

Comment: You are not providing us any code in here, that would make it really hard to help you

Comment: after "npm install" in the directory /fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript; i typed "node enrollAdmin.js" but that returned the above type of error

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?  If using Windows 10 are you using Docker for Windows or Docker Toolbox?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for Hyperledger Fabric v2.x. The problem is port no: 7054 is missing in **test** network.

In Linux (try if it works in virtual box), one way to solve is fresh restart from fabcar folder (not test network folder) then run again.

`cd $HOME/fabric-samples/fabcar`

`./startFabric.sh javascript` (by default it's goLang)

A fresh restart of the network will occur as "startFabric.sh" contains network up, down, chaincode installing, all in one.
Now try again:

`node enrollAdmin.js`

Worked for me.

Extra: Now you can run `node registerUser.js` and `node invoke.js` if you were about to use invoke.js .

Answer (score 1):

Your node application cannot connect to the Fabric CA server running in the container - so either it is not running, has failed or possibly you have some firewall or other connectivity problem.

You can test connectivity by using `wget` or `curl` or a browser to hit this URL - http://localhost:7054/api/v1/cainfo  and until you can hit this URL your enrollAdmin program will fail.

I don't use windows, but `docker ps` on Linux would tell me if the ca container was running, and `docker logs ca.example.com` would give me the log of the ca container (assuming you are running the fabcar sample on the basic sample network.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. This worked for me:

- Open VirtualBox Manager and select the “default” VM
- Click “Settings”, “Network”, “Advanced”, “Port Forwarding”.
- Create a new rule by clicking the “+” sign on the right and entering the following: Name -> “ca”, Host Port -> 7054, Guest Port -> 7054.
- You can leave the Host IP and Guest IP unspecified.

Source: 
https://developer.ibm.com/opentech/2017/11/29/running-hyperledger-fabric-windows-revised/